# Find Average in 2D array: FIXED

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, average

Here is a follow up on my previous program. It won't print the correct information for average. Please help.

PRINT

```
Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company
----------------------------------------------------------------
Name              |Paramount    |Century Fox    |Warner    |WaterFront    |Total

Alyssa    |        20|        30|         0|        40|         0|                   |90

Total: 90
Average: inf
Max: 40
```

My CODE: I am trying to add the average totals inside my print array. There seems to return some unknown information in the required field and I can't seem to figure out why. I hope someone can help me soon!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "motionPicture.h"
#include <iomanip> //to use setw
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int motionPicture :: count = 0;

motionPicture :: motionPicture() {

    //initalize the table
    for (int i =0; i < rows; i++){

            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){

                    table[i][j] =0;
            }//end j for loop
    }//end i for loop
}//end constructor
```

Part of input from my getData() function:

```
    int rowNum=0;
    rowNum++;
    string1[count] = name;
    count++;

    cout <<"Input the data in the following format."<<endl;
    cout <<"Motion Picture Number <space>  Cost of movies "<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter -1 <space> 0 to end"<<endl<<endl;

    cin >> motion >> cost;

    while (motion != -1) {

                    table[rowNum-1][motion-1] +=cost;

                    cout <<"Enter Motion Picture <space> Cost of movies" <<endl;
                    cin >> motion >>cost;
            }//end cost while
```

Print array that has issues for average output

```
void motionPicture :: printArray() {
//need to pass an int in array element variable
int size =0;
size =sizeof(table)/ sizeof(table[0][0]);
double max = table[0][0];
double min = table[0][0];

cout <<"Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company"<<endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

cout<<"Name" << setw(15)<<'|'<<setw(5)<< "Paramount" <<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5)<< "Century Fox" <<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5)<<
    "Warner"<<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5) <<"WaterFront" <<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5)<<"Total"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i= 0; i <count; i++){
               double total =0;
               double average = 0;
               cout<<string1[i]<<setw(5)<<'|';

         for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {

               //cout <<string1[i]<<"\t";
               cout <<setw(10)<<table[i][j]<<'|';
               //input total

               total += table[i][j];
              // double totalSales = total;
//              average = i[i][j] + j[i][j]'//totalSales/(i*j);
              average= total/table[i][j];
               if (table[i][j] > min)
                         max = table[i][j];
               else if (table[0][0] < min)
                         min = table[i][j];

         }//end j loop

    cout <<setw(20)<<'|'<<total<<"\n";
    cout<<endl;
    cout <<"Total: "<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"Average: " <<average/table[rowNum][motion]<<endl;
    cout<<"Max: " <<max<<endl<<endl;

    }//end i loop
}//end print
```

**FUNCTION CORRECTION**

```
void motionPicture :: printArray() {
//need to pass an int in array element variable
int size =0;
size =sizeof(table)/ sizeof(table[0][0]);
double max = table[0][0]++;
double min = table[0][0]++;


cout <<"Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company"<<endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

cout<<"Name" << setw(10)<<'|'<<setw(5)<< "Paramount" <<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5)<< "Cent Fox" <<setw(6)<<'|'<<setw(5)<<
    "Warner"<<setw(8)<<'|'<<setw(5) <<"WaterFront" <<setw(4)<<'|'<<setw(5)<<"Total"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i= 0; i <count; i++){
               double total =0;
               double average = 0;
               cout<<string1[i]<<setw(8)<<'|';

         for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {

               //cout <<string1[i]<<"\t";
               cout <<setw(7)<<table[i][j]<<setw(7)<<'|'<<setw(7);
               //input total

               total += table[i][j];
              average = total/columns;
               if (table[i][j] > min)
                         max = table[i][j];
               else if (table[0][0] < min)
                         min = table[i][j];



         }//end j loop

    cout <<setw(5)<<total<<"\n";
    cout<<endl;
    cout <<"Total: "<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"Average: " <<average<<endl;
    cout<<"Max: " <<max<<endl<<endl;

    }//end i loop
}//end print
```

**CORRECT PRINT! :)**

```
Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company
----------------------------------------------------------------
Name         |Paramount    |Cent Fox     |Warner       |WaterFront   |Total

Alyssa       |     22      |     20      |      0      |      0      |   42

Total: 42
Average: 10.5
Max: 22

Wes       |     40      |     60      |      0      |      0      |  100

Total: 100
Average: 25
Max: 60
```

Comment: Too much irrelevant code to dig through.

Comment: should I only show my print array then?

Comment: Please see the help center on generating a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Commented-out code shouldn't be included, nor fancy formatting (unless it's a question about formatting), or *"Welcome to our storing system for your account information"*. If input isn't your problem then it's better to just hardcode the data into the program. Whatever the minimal program is that demonstrates the aspect of the problem you want to ask about--that's what the code sample should be. *And be sure your sample *compiles* and demonstrates the problem!*

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for? just my print array?

Comment: @AlyssaCooke Well, your program does need to *compile*.  You've edited and reduced it.  But that edit removed the definition of `table`...which is important.  Also, how many categories do you need?  You have 4 companies here, can you demonstrate a problem with just two?  One?  Can they be called "A" and "B" and not confuse the question with "extra" domain data?  Are dashes needed?  It becomes easier to see the problem when you pare it down to the essentials...explain very precisely what you expected vs what you got...along with the minimal amount of code that can run to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: im trying to shorten my code but issue is... I have a lot that gives information that may be needed. :/ sorry if I'm still giving too much. And the dashes are what print my code output. I guess I could remove it but I don't understand why it would need to be for this situation.

Comment: Why don't you write a single function that calculates and returns the average of the array and nothing else. Printing "Paramount" has no relevance to your calculation.

Comment: I thought about that but didn't know how to connect my avg function with the variables in the other's since most will live and die within the functions

Comment: `double calcAverage(const double table[size][size])` or something? I use vectors so can't remember the exact array syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`average` should be calculated by dividing the total by the number of entries. You have the total in `total` and the number of entries in `columns` (assuming you want a column average). So you just need to have this at the end of your column (j) loop.

```
average = total / columns;
```

and print that. Or, more simply you could just print out `total / columns`.

Comment: I would like the average for all the columns totaled. I tried this code but when I have Paramount = 20 and Cent Fox = 30 (total is 50) then it gives me Average: 10

Comment: well I guess that would make sense since there is 5 columns. the rest =0 so technically that's correct. Guess that's the best I can do unless the person enters information for all columns only.

Comment: thanks. I guess it was that simple. I was trying to figure out some code that was way too complicated.

Comment: Normally it is that simple, but if a zero entry isn't meant to be included in the average, you would need to keep a count of how many entries were non zero and then divide by that. In that case you would have to have a special case for when the count was zero to avoid a divide-by-zero error.